# continuous run app in background. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

in my app, I am connecting my app to BLE device. and I am fetching BLE data from BLE device at every 1 second. it working fine when I do this in the foreground.but I want to do same in the background even when the app will be in the background I need to fetch data continuously from BLE device. right now its stoped automatically after 2 minutes.

Please let me know if it's feasible or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html
You may need a background mode to allow your app to run in background.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Background Mode in your project settings under capabilities tab. Under background modes you will find a few modes that satisfy various purposes of running an app in background. From these you have to enable the ones that you think are suitable according to the task that your app will perform in background. I think, you should enable external accessory communication and background fetch.

Also you need to implement a background task when your app enters background. This is done in app delegate's didEnterBackground method.

Comment: could you detail how to implement the app delegate's method in didEnterBackground ?

Answer (score 1):

**Apple documentation**

Apps that work with Bluetooth peripherals can ask to be woken up if the peripheral delivers an update when the app is suspended. This support is important for **Bluetooth-LE** accessories that deliver data at regular intervals, such as a Bluetooth heart rate belt. You enable support for using bluetooth accessories from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the bluetooth-central value in your app’s Info.plist file.) When you enable this mode, the Core Bluetooth framework keeps open any active sessions for the corresponding peripheral. In addition, new data arriving from the peripheral causes the system to wake up the app so that it can process the data. The system also wakes up the app to process accessory connection and disconnection notifications.
In iOS 6, an app can also operate in peripheral mode with Bluetooth accessories. To act as a Bluetooth accessory, you must enable support for that mode from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the bluetooth-peripheral value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Enabling this mode lets the Core Bluetooth framework wake the app up briefly in the background so that it can handle accessory-related requests. Apps woken up for these events should process them and return as quickly as possible so that the app can be suspended again.
Any app that supports the background processing of Bluetooth data must be session-based and follow a few basic guidelines:

**Apps must provide an interface that allows the user to start and stop the delivery of Bluetooth events. That interface should then open or close the session as appropriate.**

**Upon being woken up, the app has around 10 seconds to process the data. Ideally, it should process the data as fast as possible and allow itself to be suspended again. However, if more time is needed, the app can use the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method to request additional time; it should do so only when absolutely necessary, though.**